# How to have an initial state with no option selected with UIButton (popup/pulldown button)?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uimenu, uiaction

I have this particular code

```
let genderOptions = ["Male".localized, "Female".localized]
    .map { UIAction(title: $0, state: .off, handler: {_ in }) }
genderButton.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
genderButton.menu = UIMenu(children: genderOptions)
```

[image]

I have set all the `UIAction`'s `state` to `.off`, but still it is selecting the first item by default. Below is the Apple's documentation.

[image]

But when I print the `selectedElements`, it prints the following:

```
print(genderButton.menu?.selectedElements)
```

[image]
even though all the `UIAction` items `state = .off`, it prints an array with the first item as selected.

**Q: How to have an initial state without any selection? Is popup button a good option to use here or should I use UITextField with UIPickerView?**
If anyone could give a complete solution, it would be great.

Comment: Presumably you have set `showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set `changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true`, you can add a hidden (with the `.hidden` attribute) action as the first action:

```
var genderOptions = [UIAction(title: "Select Gender", attributes: [.hidden], handler: {_ in })]
genderOptions.append(contentsOf: ["Male", "Female"]
    .map { UIAction(title: $0, handler: {_ in }) })
```

The button selects the first action and uses its title as the button's title. The user can then select one of the other two actions. But they cannot select the hidden action.

The `.disabled` attribute also prevents the user from selecting the action, but the option is still visible.

See also: [`UIMenuElement.Attributes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenuelement/attributes)